# Insert default values in a list to make it of fixed length

Tags: python-2.7, list

List could be of max length 4. Whenever it is short of max length "default value" is to be inserted at the beginning of the list.
Example:

```
input = [1,2]
output= ["default value","default value",1,2]

input[1,2,3]
output = ["default value",1,2,3]
```

I am doing it as:

```
if len(score_list) == 3:
    score_list.insert(0,"did not file")
if len(score_list) == 2:
    score_list.insert(0,"did not file")
    score_list.insert(1,"did not file")
if len(score_list) == 1:
    score_list.insert(0,"did not file")
    score_list.insert(1,"did not file")
    score_list.insert(2,"did not file")
if len(score_list) == 0:
    score_list.insert(0,"did not file")
    score_list.insert(1,"did not file")
    score_list.insert(2,"did not file")
    score_list.insert(4,"did not file")
```

Please help me to achieve this in a elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps) in more readable way:

```
score_list = [1, 2]

score_list = ["did not file" for x in range(4)][len(score_list):] + score_list[:4]

print score_list
```

Results:

```
input = []
output = ['did not file', 'did not file', 'did not file', 'did not file']

input = [1, 2]
output = ['did not file', 'did not file', 1, 2]

input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
output = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate lists with the `+` operator, and multiply a list by an integer to repeat it that number of times. Combining those two things together, you can do:

```
score_list = ["did not file"]*(4-len(score_list)) + score_list
```

If you need to do the modification in place, you could do a slice assignment instead of concatenating:

```
score_list[:0] = ["did not file"] * (4-len(score_list))
```